# I am finding it difficult to return an html table after an ajax call

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

the whole ideal is to select a date range which will be used as parameters to execute the query by the php file. in chrome network tools, payload shows the dates where sent but i am not able to get the table displayed

This is the ajax code to make the call

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function()
        {
          $('#form').submit(function(event)
          {
            event.preventDefault();
            var forminput = new FormData($(this)[0]);
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"exec/sales_calc.php",
                data:forminput,
                async:true,
                cache:false,
                contentType:false,
                processData:false,
                dataType:"html",
                success:function(text)
                {
                      $("#myDiv").html(text);
                },
                error:function(){
                  alert("error in form submission");
                }
              });
          });
        });
        </script>
```

This is the php code to execute the query

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once '../../config/config.php';
require_once '../exec/class.validate.php';


if(isset($_SESSION['ADMIN_USER']))
{
  $validate = new validate($con);

  $from =$validate->validated($con,$_POST['from']);
  $to = $validate->validated($con,$_POST['to']);
  
  $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM purchases WHERE sold_out > 0 AND purchase_date >= $from AND purchase_date <= $to");

  if($sql)
  {
    while($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
    {
        $item_name =$record['item_name'];
        $selling_price = $record['sell_price'];
        $sold_out = $record['sold_out'];
        $total = $selling_price * $sold_out;
      ?>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row"><?php echo $item_name;?></th>
        <td><?php echo $selling_price;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $sold_out;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $total;?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php
    }
  }
  else
  {
    echo 'Error: couldnt load sold items';
  }
}
?>
```

Below is the html for that provides the date date input to be sent

```
<form class="" id="form" method="post">
                      <label for="from">From:</label>
                      <input class="form-group" type="date" id="from" name="from">
                      <label for="to">To:</label>
                      <input class="form-group" type="date" id="to" name="to">
                      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button">Refresh</button>
                    </form>
```

The returned data which in this case is the table must be displayed in **tbody** tag with the id #myDiv

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Check The data which can get by database using `print_r()` and `exit()` function
Ex:

```
print_r($sql);

 exit();
```

Comment: Thanks. I realized the path to my class file was not well specified.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check if going to `sales_calc.php` from your browser works, if doesn't, the problem is in that file. If not, try debugging how's `$('#form').submit(function(event)` being called (the fastest but not the "ideal" way is writing a `console.log()` just when the submit function starts to execute).
Let me know if that helped

Comment: Thanks. Everything works fine. Will factor this in and see how I can improve the code.